# Simple Harmonic Wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator

What is the minimum distance between particles in same phase  having same speed ? How should I approach this problem ?

Comment: Hi Abhilasha and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Sorry , @JohnRennie I'm new here. Will take care in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particles which are one wavelength apart have the same speed in the same direction, so they also have the same phase. Particles which are half a wavelength apart have the same speed but opposite direction, so they are in anti-phase.